# How to configure SonarLint in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, sonarqube, sonarlint

I was using SonarLint plugin in IntelliJ IDEA by using the url of our project. However, I want to configura it independently for my custom projects, but I am confused how should I do that. Could you pls clarify me about the following issues?

**1.** What is the SonarCloud and SonarCube options for configuring the SonarLint plugin in IntelliJ IDEA?

**2.** If I have not a specific url or server for SonarQube, how should I configure the plugin? Which section should I select (SonarCloud and SonarCube)?

Answer (score 3):

### SONAR LINT SETUP

[SonarLint Logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEah6.png)

Configuring SonarLint in IntelliJ IDEA is a straightforward process. SonarLint is a code analysis tool that helps you identify and fix code quality issues in your Java, Kotlin, and other supported languages. Here's a step-by-step guide on how to configure SonarLint in IntelliJ IDEA:

Note: Before starting, make sure you have IntelliJ IDEA installed and your project is opened in the IDE.

***Install SonarLint Plugin:***

If you haven't already installed the SonarLint plugin, you can do so by going to IntelliJ IDEA's settings:

Open IntelliJ IDEA.
Go to "File" > "Settings" (or "IntelliJ IDEA" > "Preferences" on macOS).
In the left sidebar, select "Plugins."
In the search bar, type "SonarLint" to find the SonarLint plugin.
Click the "Install" button to install the plugin.

***Configure SonarLint:***

Once the plugin is installed, you need to configure it:

Go to "File" > "Settings" (or "IntelliJ IDEA" > "Preferences" on macOS).
In the left sidebar, you should now see "SonarLint" listed.
Click on "SonarLint" to open its settings.

*Connect to a SonarQube Server (Optional):*

If you are using SonarQube to manage your code analysis rules, you can configure the SonarLint plugin to connect to your SonarQube server:

In the SonarLint settings, click on "Server Configuration."
Click the "+" button to add a new server configuration.
Enter the server details, including the server URL, authentication credentials (if required), and organization (if applicable).
Click "Test Connection" to verify that the configuration is correct.
Click "Apply" and then "OK" to save the server configuration.

*Binding Your Project (Optional):*

Binding your project to a SonarQube project allows SonarLint to use the rules and settings defined on the SonarQube server:

In the SonarLint settings, click on "Project Configuration."
If you've already connected to a SonarQube server, select the server configuration you created in step 3.
Click "Bind Project" to associate your project with a SonarQube project. This step is optional, but it enables better rule synchronization.

***Code Analysis:***

Now that SonarLint is configured, you can perform code analysis:

Open your project files in IntelliJ IDEA.
Right-click on a file, directory, or the whole project in the Project Explorer.
Choose "Analyze" > "Run SonarLint" from the context menu.
SonarLint will analyze your code and highlight any issues directly in the editor.

***View Issues:***

To view and manage the code issues identified by SonarLint:

Open the "SonarLint" tool window in IntelliJ IDEA (you can find it on the right side).
In the "SonarLint" window, you'll see a list of issues categorized by severity.
Double-click on an issue to navigate to its location in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find the documentation [here](https://github.com/sonar-intellij-plugin/sonar-intellij-plugin).

I don't think the plugin will work if you don't have any installed SonarQube instance, or a SonarCloud account. The plugin needs to interact with a server to retrieve coding rules.

Comment: Yeah, but what about I do not have neither sonarclous account nor installed sonarqube instance, and still want to check my code using a default rules?